# Copy string from browser to xterm running vi, in KDE

Tags: linux, copy-paste, kde

I would like to paste some URLs (text) into scripts, and to do so it would be most convenient if I could copy and paste from the browser to a xterm instance of vi.

How can I copy (control-C) and then paste the string copied, into an instance of vi?

I am using Slackware 14.2, with KDE.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the string as normal. Open up `vi` in `xterm`. Then change to paste mode by typing `:set paste` and then use `Shift+Insert` to paste the string. Paste mode avoids unexpected effects that might be present when pasting using insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

I usually copy from the browser, then I go ti vi, set it into 'insert' then right-click to paste.

(I'm talking of vi running into a terminal-emulator window, not on a plain TTY)